# Textarea character counter

Tags: javascript

```
window.onload = function() {                                                                                        
var text_max = 200;
$('#count_message').html('0 / ' + text_max );

$('#text').keyup (function() {
var text_length = $('#text').val().length;
var text_remaining = text_max - text_length;

$('#count_message').html(text_length + ' / ' + text_max);
});}
```

I have this script that's counting characters in textarea. But its implemented in textarea where is already something writen.

simply, i just wondering how to make this script check for characters on page load and not after i press something.

i mean. when i reload page there is 0/200 character remaining but there are already like 150 characters in that textarea

Comment: It says "0/200" because your initialization has an explicit "0"; it doesn't check the length.

Comment: Simple solution would be changing `$('#count_message').html('0 / ' + text_max );` to `$('#count_message').html($('#text').val().length + ' / ' + text_max);`

Comment: Yes that's exactly what i was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Option 1:

Trigger the `keyup` event on page load like:

```
$('#count_message').keyup();
```

### Option 2:

Create a `keyup` event handler function and use it on `keyup` and also on page load like:

```
$(function() {
  var text_max = 200;

  function onKeyup() {
    var text_length = $('#text').val().length;
    var text_remaining = text_max - text_length;
    $('#count_message').html(text_length + ' / ' + text_max);
  }

  onKeyup();
  $('#count_message').keyup(onKeyup);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Slight modification in your code

```
var text_max = 200;


var text_length=$('#text').val().length;
var text_remaining =0;

$('#text').keyup (function() {
 text_length = $('#text').val().length;
 text_remaining = text_max - text_length;
$('#count_message').html(text_length + ' / ' + text_max);
});
$('#count_message').html(text_length + ' / ' + text_max);
```